# count number of lists inside a list python

Tags: python, list, count

I have a list like this :

```
test=[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

How can i count how many lists i have inside list called `test` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: This is not exactly a dup since op wants to know how many lists resides in his list of lists rather than how many elements are inside.

Answer (score 2):

You will utilize the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function for this task:

> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

```
>>> test=[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1],
...     [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1],
...     [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1],
...     [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0],[0,0,0,0]]
>>> len(test)
18
```